# zuul passes a full stacktrace back to client before it calls errorFilter, is there a wat to stop this behaviour

Tags: netflix-zuul

When zuul throws an uncaught exception, I want to log  the stack trace and pass a simple message back to the client.

Reading the docs, this is carried out with error filter. I log the error and create an error response.   But when running the code, Its passes the stack trace back to the client before it gets to my errorfilter functionality.

Is there something I need to set, so when an unhandled exception is the error filter does all the work.

There is a way around this, capture the exception in the calling filter. but then that seems to defeat the purpose of the ErrorFilter.

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix.

in the properties or yml need to set the following zuul.SendErrorFilter.error.disable=true